# WSO2 Identity Server: SOAP Services failing to update user claim values after first time

Tags: claims-based-identity, wso2-identity-server

I have been using WSO2 IS 5.3.0. I am using SOAP service of RemoteUserStoreManagerService. Operation is setUserClaimValues. This is used to update value of failed login attempts by user. However, this service calls work only for the first time and then it does not work until wso2 restarted. The SOAP service does not return any error though any time.

When I hit it through SOAP-UI, I get following response with blank body.

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 21:03:16 GMT
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
```

**SOAP Request for setting value**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://common.mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:setUserClaimValues>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:userName>superadmin03</ser:userName>

          <ser:claims>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:claimURI>http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts</xsd:claimURI>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:value>2</xsd:value>
         </ser:claims>

      </ser:setUserClaimValues>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**SOAP Response for getting value**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:getUserClaimValues>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:userName>superadmin03</ser:userName>

      </ser:getUserClaimValues>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I call getUserClaimValues for same attribute, it does not show me new value but same old value.

I am trying to update value for *http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts*

Here's what I found in logs in WSO2 though SOAP service does not return any faults.

```
[2017-03-22 16:03:20,012]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  Illegal access attempt at [2017-03-22 16:03:20,0012] from IP address 127.0.0.1 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteUserStoreManagerService
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Regards,

Sagar Shah

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have enabled both identityMgtEventListeners in identity.xml file.

Either

***org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener***

or
***org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener***

Should be enabled at once.

Thanks
Isura.

Comment: That was a good catch. By default, "org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener" is enabled. As per article on "https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/User+Account+Locking" I enabled "org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener" and got the above issue. I reverted this file and kept it to default (just enabled "org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener") and it worked fine. But if I enable the other one and disable "org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener", then it does not seem to work

Comment: When I keep "org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener" enabled and other one disabled, WSO2 does not lock the user account on invalid authentication attempts. Isn't there a way to address this?

Comment: Then you need to configure account locking in resident IDP UI. Not from the identity-mgt.properties file

Comment: Appreciate your answers! So in this scenario, should I be reverting all 4 properties of identity-mgt.properties? Which listener should I be enabling? Is there any article/library link describing such a scenario?

Comment: I tried this option by setting config in resident IDP through admin console UI. After that when invoking oauth2 request to authenticate a user (with incorrect password) after reaching max failed attempts (as per configuration), I am getting this error json format. "{
  "error_description": "Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION",
  "error": "invalid_grant"
}". Is there an easy way to determine from response, if account is locked or not?

Comment: I have a issue where the "http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts" in IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA is not getting updated after the user has entered valid credentials

Answer (score 0):

I have a issue where the user's FailedLoginAttempt is not getting reset to 0 after one successful login action.